# JDBC pre-fetch when fetching SYS_REFCURSOR opened in an Oracle stored function

Tags: oracle, jdbc, prefetch, sys-refcursor

I was reading some interesting stuff about JDBC pre-fetch size, but I cannot find any answer to a few questions:

1. The Java app I'm working on is designed to fetch rows from cursors opened and returned by functions within PL/SQL packages. I was wondering whether the pre-fetch default setting of the JDBC driver is actually affecting the fetching process or not, being the SQL statements parsed and opened within the Oracle database. I tried setting the fetch size on the JBoss configuration file and printing the value taken from the method setFetchSize(). The new value (100, just for testing purpose) was returned but I see no difference in how the application performs.
2. I also read this pre-fetching is enhancing performance by reducing the number of round-trips between the client and the database server, but how can I measure the number of round trips in order to verify and quantify the actual benefits I can eventually get by tuning the pre-fetch size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes the Oracle JDBC thin driver will use the configured prefetch size when fetching from any cursor whether the cursor was opened by the client or from within a stored proc.
2. The easiest way to count the roundtrips is to look a the sqlnet trace. You can turn on sqlnet tracing on the server-side by adding `trace_level_server = 16` to your sqlnet.ora file (again on the server as JDBC thin doesn't use sqlnet.ora). Each foreground process will then dump the network traffic in a trace file. You can then see the network packets exchanged with the client and count the roundtrips. By default the driver fetches rows 10 by 10. But since you have increased the fetch size to 100 it should fetch up to that number of rows in one single roundtrip.

Note that unless your client is far away from your server (significant ping time) then the cost of a roundtrip won't be high and unless you're fetching a very high number of rows (10,000s) you won't see much difference in performance in increasing the fetch size. The default 10 usually works fine for most OLTP applications. In your client is far away then you can also consider increasing the SDU size (maximum size of a sqlnet packet). The default is 8k but you can increase it up to 2MB in 12.2.